# Accessing elements in json file returned from TVMaze.com using VB-JSON lib with VB6

Tags: json, vb.net, vb6

Anyone know how to access the individual items in this returned json? 
eg: "id", "name", "tvrageid"

This code works with this File:
Partial code:

```
   Private Sub cmdReadJSON_Click()
   Dim p As Object

   cd.ShowOpen

   If cd.FileName <> "" Then
      Set p = JSON.parse(ReadTextFile(cd.FileName))
      If Not (p Is Nothing) Then
         If JSON.GetParserErrors <> "" Then
            MsgBox JSON.GetParserErrors, vbInformation, "Parsing Error(s) 
occured"
         Else
            MsgBox "Base item count: " & p.Count
            MsgBox "JSON toString: " & Left(JSON.toString(p), 2000)
            MsgBox "Id: " & p.Item("id") & " Name: " & p.Item("name")
            MsgBox "TVRage: " & p.Item("externals")("tvrage")
         End If
      Else
         MsgBox "An error occurred parsing " & cd.FileName
      End If
   End If      
End Sub
```

The above code works with this
xxxx://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls

```
{"id":82,"url":"xxxx://www.tvmaze.com/shows/82/game-of-thrones","name":"Game of Thrones","type":"Scripted","language":"English","genres":["Drama","Adventure","Fantasy"],"status":"Running","runtime":60,"premiered":"2011-04-17","rating":{"average":9.5},"weight":50,"network":{"id":8,"name":"HBO","country":{"name":"United States","code":"US","timezone":"America/New_York"}},"webChannel":null,"externals":{"tvrage":24493,"thetvdb":121361},"image":{"medium":"xxxx://tvmazecdn.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/581.jpg","original":"xxxx://tvmazecdn.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/0/581.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Based on the bestselling book series A Song of Ice and Fire by George R.R. Martin, this sprawling new HBO drama is set in a world where summers span decades and winters can last a lifetime. From the scheming south and the savage eastern lands, to the frozen north and ancient Wall that protects the realm from the mysterious darkness beyond, the powerful families of the Seven Kingdoms are locked in a battle for the Iron Throne. This is a story of duplicity and treachery, nobility and honor, conquest and triumph. In the Game of Thrones, you either win or you die.</p>","_links":{"self":{"href":"xxxx://api.tvmaze.com/shows/82"},"previousepisode":{"href":"xxxx://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/162186"}}}
```

But does not work with this file:
Example:  xxxx://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=hawaii five-0

Returns a json file that contains:

```
[{"score":7.8952017,"show":{"id":24,"url":"xxxx://www.tvmaze.com/shows/24/hawaii-five-0","name":"Hawaii Five-0","type":"Scripted","language":"English","genres":["Action","Adventure","Crime"],"status":"Running","runtime":60,"premiered":"2010-09-20","rating":{"average":8.4},"weight":22,"network":{"id":2,"name":"CBS","country":{"name":"United States","code":"US","timezone":"America/New_York"}},"webChannel":null,"externals":{"tvrage":24840,"thetvdb":164541},"image":{"medium":"xxxx://tvmazecdn.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/294.jpg","original":"xxxx://tvmazecdn.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/0/294.jpg"},"summary":"<p>HAWAII FIVE-0 is a contemporary take on the classic series about a new elite federalized task force whose mission is to wipe out the crime that washes up on the Islands' sun-drenched beaches. Detective Steve McGarrett, a decorated Naval officer-turned-cop, returns to Oahu to investigate his father's murder and stays after Hawaii's Governor persuades him to head up the new team: his rules, her backing, no red tape and full blanket authority to hunt down the biggest \"game\" in town. Joining McGarrett is Detective Danny \"Danno\" Williams, a newly relocated ex-New Jersey cop - a working man in paradise who prefers skyscrapers to the coastline - but who's committed to keeping the Islands safe for his 8-year-old daughter; and Chin Ho Kelly, an ex-Honolulu Police Detective, and former protégé of McGarrett's father, wrongly accused of corruption and relegated to a federal security patrol. Chin's cousin, Kono Kalakaua, is a beautiful and fearless native, fresh out of the academy and eager to establish herself among the department's elite. McGarrett, repairing his relationship with his estranged sister Mary Ann, vows to bring closure to their father's case, while the state's brash new FIVE-0 unit, who may spar and jest among themselves, is determined to eliminate the seedy elements from the 50th state.</p>","updated":1442079542,"_links":{"self":{"href":"xxxx://api.tvmaze.com/shows/24"},"previousepisode":{"href":"xxxx://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/152994"},"nextepisode":{"href":"xxxx://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/167425"}}}}]
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to explain and expand on  "does not work".  Since it is a third party lib, have you sought help from the author?  That would parse quite easily using VB.NET in VS Express or VS Community which are free.

Comment: This is either vb.net or vb6.. which one?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's not the Lib. It's my code. To reference the `id` I needed to use 
`p.item(1).item("show").item("id")` 
this returns `24` as it should.

This is VB6 not VB.NET